# Hex in char array

Tags: c

If the following is a one byte array:

```
char arr[] = "\xFF";
```

If we do the following:

```
char arr[] = "\xFFmyrandomstringappendedafterbyte";
```

printing it would result in this:

```
byteValueGoesHEREmyrandomstringappendedafterbyte
```

However, if I try to do the following:

```
char arr[] = "\xFF98";
```

It will result in a warning:

```
warning: hex escape sequence out of range
```

It treats `98` as part of the hexcode. However, I would it to be treated as a string (as  is `myrandomstringappendedafterbyte`).

I would like to have this as output `byteValueGoesHERE98`.

How can this be achieved without a **whitespace**? How can I denote that 98 should be treated as a string?

Comment: @KenWhite Apologies, I have updated my question. It was too vague before.

Comment: We need to see your actual code.

Comment: `arr[]` is not a _one byte array_.  It is a _two byte array_.  2nd byte is `'\0'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When string literals have only whitespace (or nothing) between them, the preprocessor combines them into a single string literal, but this does not "merge" escape sequences. So you can just write your desired string using two strings:

```
char arr[] = "\xFF" "98";
```

This is four bytes including the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: Alternatively, note that octal and unicode escapes have a finite length.